# Event trigger is not working inside ItemControl

Tags: wpf, silverlight, itemscontrol, event-triggers

I have a Item control which fills by a list, and list is collection of two parameters 'Time' and 'Description'. For it, i am using a HyperLinkButton for time and a Label for description.

What i want is that, i want to create click event using EventTrigger of hyperLink button in Main viewModel. My code is:

```
<ItemsControl 
    x:Name="transcriptionTextControl" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfTranscription, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Time}">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Content="Time"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                Command="{Binding HyperLinkButtonCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding 
                                    ElementName=transcriptionTextControl }" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </HyperlinkButton>
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When i build project, it doesn't give error but ICommand for hyperLink, shows warning as 'Cannot resolve symbol HyperLinkButtonCommand', while this event trigger is working fine outside this .

Not getting, what is actual problem behind it, plz give your valuable suggestion...

Comment: Why are you using triggers anyway? The HyperlinkButton has the Command properties already.

Answer (score 1):

First off,

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding HyperLinkButtonCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding 
        ElementName=transcriptionTextControl }" />
```

The Binding is trying to locate a property called `HyperLinkButtonCommand` on the instance of the type that is contained within `MyCollectionOfTranscription` (you don't need to bind to this two-way).

(Side note, sending an ItemsControl into your Command is *not* MVVM.)

The `ItemsControl` iterates through each element in this collection, creates a copy of the template defined in `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`, and sets the `BindingContext` equal to this element (I assume its a Transcript).  You can tell this from the warnings you get from the binding failing to find your `HyperLinkButtonCommand` if you crank up databinding debug settings.

[image]

Assuming

1. `HyperLinkButtonCommand` is a command defined in your ViewModel, and
2. The root of this xaml is a Window (could be a UserControl, but am assuming here)
3. Your ViewModel is the `DataContext` of the Window

you can change the binding to the following and it should work (or you should get a clue from it)

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding HyperLinkButtonCommand, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding 
        ElementName=transcriptionTextControl }" />
```

I prefer just to give my root an `x:Name` of "root" and use "ElementName=root" in cases like this.

Comment: Now my code is not giving warning, but hyperLinkButtonCommand is not triggering.

Comment: Let me explain in detail. I have set code for HyperLinkButtonCommand property in ViewModel as
HyperLinkButtonCommand=new DelegateCommand(HyperLinkButtonAction, CanHyperLinkButton);


public ICommand HyperLinkButtonCommand { get; set; }
        public void HyperLinkButtonAction(object param)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HII");
        }
private bool CanHyperLinkButton(object param)
        {
            return true;
        }

And at view, there will be repeatation of time and description field, so i want to show messageBox on each click of 'Time' hyperlink button, but its not firing.

Comment: @user1298386: Edit your question and add the method where you are instantiating your command.

Comment: public MainViewModel()
        {
HyperLinkButtonCommand=new DelegateCommand(HyperLinkButtonAction, CanHyperLinkButton);
}

Comment: @user1298386 Looks right, afaict.  Crank up the debug messages like I illustrated.  Also, try making a small project which replicates only what you are trying to get working and see if you can't fix the issue. then compare to your full project.

Comment: Finally i have got the solution. All, who are facing this problem, just use this code for binding.

<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperLinkButtonCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=stkPanel }" />

Here LayoutRoot is name of grid and stkPanel is name of StachPanel inside ItemSControl